# Reading Razor View Variables Programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have "widgets" contained within partial views and iterate over these files to build an available widget list. Within these views there are two variables

```
@{ ViewBag.Name = "Test Widget"; }
@{ ViewBag.Description = "This is a test widget"; }
```

self explanatory. Is there a way using RazorEngine (or any other way) to "read" these variables out so I can show the value of `ViewBag.Description` in my widget list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) with a custom base view could be used for this purpose:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // don't ask me about this line :-)
        // it's used to ensure that the Microsoft.CSharp assembly is loaded
        bool loaded = typeof(Binder).Assembly != null;

        Razor.SetTemplateBase(typeof(FooTemplateBase<>));
        string template = 
@"@{ ViewBag.Name = ""Test Widget""; }
@{ ViewBag.Description = ""This is a test widget""; }";
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        var result = Razor.Parse(template, model);
        Console.WriteLine(model.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(model.Description);
    }
}

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public abstract class FooTemplateBase<T> : TemplateBase<T>
    {
        public dynamic ViewBag
        {
            get
            {
                return Model;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think we have basically the same answer, just with two different parsers, not sure which is better, Razor Generator is created by an Architect on the ASP.NET team which is the only reason I would prefer that over RazorEngine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RazorGenerator to actually compile the views, then do a sample execution of them to be able to read the data.

See this article on unit testing the razor views, a similar thing may work for you:

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/unit-test-your-mvc-views-using-razor.html

```
var view = new Index();

// Set up the data that needs to be accessed by the view
view.ViewBag.Message = "Testing";

// Render it in an HtmlAgilityPack HtmlDocument. Note that
// you can pass a 'model' object here if your view needs one.
// Generally, what you do here is similar to how a controller
//action sets up data for its view.
HtmlDocument doc = view.RenderAsHtml();

//recall name and description
var name = view.ViewBag.Name;
var description = view.ViewBag.Description;
```

Here is some additional info on the Razor Generator from Phil Haack: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/01/text-templating-using-razor-the-easy-way.aspx

Comment: Hi Paul, I've accepted Darins answer because I already use RazorEngine within my project. Your answer seems correct also, have an upvote.